# Restricting access to AD roles in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, roles

I'm fairly new to ASP.net development, and am wondering how to continue with a certain problem.  I have access to an existing website that uses a single web page to display multiple different reports (the type of report to be displayed determined by a query string).  A set of links to different reports is shown on the entry default.aspx page.  This web site is accessed internally by users on a domain with their credentials stored in an Active Directory user store.

I have been asked to upgrade the security of this web site so that different users will be presented with a different list of reports dependent on their AD role.  I understand security trimming can be used in conjunction with a sitemap provider to restrict what different users or roles have access to in an ASP menu control.  Is it possible to use security trimming with something like aliased URL's, where the alias refers to the report page with the query string?

Any other straight-forward way of achieving this (preferably with the mapping of roles to reports in a single location) is fine.

Thanks for your help.
Norman

Comment: Where are the reports stored?  In a database?  If so, it might make most sense to integrate roles within the same database.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you can check if user belongs to certain role using one of [WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kc03hk7.aspx) overload. What you need to do is to associate roles with reports in some configurable store (for example, database, xml file etc) and then use this information to decide if particular report is applicable to logged in user and then control visibility of the report link.

Answer (score 0):

1-Firstly You need to change authentication mode to Windows authentication from within your web.config File.

2-Secondly Use LoginView Control from your ToolBox Login Section

3- in your LoginView Control Select Edit RoleGroups Link

4- Start Adding The Roles with the same name as your AD Roles

5- after finished adding Roles to loginView you can access them from the loginView

6- Select LoginView's smart tag and views list point to a specific Role

7- Start add links to the login View for the selected Role on step number 6

8- Repeat Step 7 for each Role in the Roles List

==========================================================

Note : this solution will be fine for windows Roles (i.e) Number of Roles are constant and changes in roles are minimum